# Trying to Request Data (POST) from FLASK API with Java Script

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask, post

I am currently trying to request Data with Java Script from my API but it doesn`t work.
Everytime i POST i get the error, that "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" in FLASK.
Code of my API:

```
#http://127.0.0.1:5000/fnd
@app.route('/fnd', methods=['POST'])
def fnd():
    content = request.json
    return jsonify(content['Text'])
```

For the Post I am using JQuery AJAX Requests

```
$(function ()
{
    var output = $('#output');
    $('#checkonfake').on('click',function(){
        var texttocheck = $('#texttocheck').val();
        var datad = {"Text": texttocheck}
        console.log(datad);
        if(texttocheck != ""){
              $.ajax(
                {
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: 
                    { 
                        datad
                    },
                    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/fnd',
                    success: function (result) 
                    {
                        console.log(result);
                    },
                    error: function () 
                    {
                        console.log("error");
                    }
                });
    }
})
});
```

I have like a Input Box and a button and as soon as i press the button the request should be sent off.

Comment: If I try it with POSTMAN, the result is as following ```<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The method is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>```

Comment: you are getting that error since ```content``` is emty. The reason why you get ```The method is not allowed for the requested URL``` is that the method for ```def fnd()``` is different from what you are using with POSTMAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change code to this by string:

```
#http://127.0.0.1:5000/fnd
@app.route('/fnd', methods=['POST'])
def fnd():
    s_json = request.get_data(as_text=True)
    obj = json.loads(s_json)
    return jsonify(obj['Text'])
```

and change html code to this:

```
datad = {"aaa":"aaaa", "bbb":"bbb","Text":"Text"}
$.ajax(
    {
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(datad),
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/fnd',
        success: function (result)
        {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function ()
        {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
```

or if you wana uses json

```
@app.route('/fnd', methods=['POST'])
def fnd():
    return jsonify(request.form["Text"])
```

```
datad = {"aaa":"aaaa", "bbb":"bbb","Text":"Text"}
 $.ajax(
    {
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'POST',
        data: datad,
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/fnd',
        success: function (result)
        {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function ()
        {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
```

by the way:
i can't find the info for request.json in flask.palletsprojects.com
so.. i don;t know this param means and why it is none